# Service account key creation in GCP using rest API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hello I am using below rest api commamd to create a service account key in GCP. Running the command from cloud shell though not sure doing it correctly.

curl POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_iD/serviceAccounts/serviceaccountID.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys?key=key generated by API Key credentials

I am a service account admin but when I run this command in cloud shell I get below error. Idealy I have all access for service account still says list permisssion is required. Can anybody help?

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Permission iam.serviceAccountKeys.list is required to perform this operation on service account projects/pserviceaccountID@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your error.  The first:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
```

Is telling you that the curl command cannot look up the hostname "POST" because you omitted the -X parameter, the first part of your command should read:

```
curl -X POST
```

Next, the URL you have is not quite the  right format, as there should be no URL parameters (in this case the `?key=key` portion), as it is a POST request -- the parameters from the API would be included in the body of the request.

However, I suspect even in that case you will have a permission denied error, as curl will not manage the oauth authentication and authorization that is necessary for this request to work -- you're effectively appearing to the API as unauthenticated.  I'd recommend in this case that you use one of the client libraries to do the request, or use the gcloud command directly instead of curl.  These will both greatly simplify the management of the authentication.

There are examples in C#, Go, Node, Python and others in the documentation for the API itself, take a look here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create

The documentation for using gcloud to accomplish this is here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-gcloud

That said, if you really want to do this with curl from cloud shell (where you have an authenticated gcloud session) this is the sequence of commands you need:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECTID/serviceAccounts/SERVICEACCOUNTNAME@PROJECTID.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys
```

If you aren't on a cloud shell machine, you need to make sure you have gcloud auth first:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service account that's making the request doesn’t have the required permissions. You should either give the SA the required IAM roles described in [1], or you can use your own user by doing `gcloud auth login user@email.com` to make the call.

You’ll also need the Service Account Key Admin, as SA Admin doesn’t have iam.serviceAccountKeys.list [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#required_permissions

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference